# Is a male guardian required for women skiing in Iran?

Tags: legal, iran, female-travellers, islam, skiing

NY Mag's article [Vogue Left Out a Few Things About Skiing in Iran](http://nymag.com/thecut/2015/01/vogue-left-out-a-few-things-about-skiing-in-iran.html?mid=twitter_nymag) claims that women need a male guardian to go skiing, citing a [2011 Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/blogpost/post/iran-to-women-no-skiiing-unless-with-a-male-guardian/2011/11/10/gIQAgQ878M_blog.html?wprss=blogpost?wprss=blogpost) article. (The Islamic term for this is [mahram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram).)

The comments section disputes that this is the case.

Is a male guardian required for women to go skiing in Iran?

Answer (score 12):

Categorically NO! I am a woman, I live in Iran, I go skiing EVERY week, I wear the same gear I wear when I ski in Europe or in the US. I am never, ever accompanied by men.  Funnily enough, the slopes are the least 'Islamic' places in Iran and it is really amazing to see what young (unmarried) men and woman get up to there - it would make any Westerner jealous.  There is house music playing at the ski lodges as well as at the ski-lifts....The NY Mag article could not be further from the truth.

Comment: I'm only curious mind you.... is this 'the way it is' or is it 'breaking the letter of the law, but overlooked by everyone?'